# How to know if i have moved mouse to the Left or Right

Tags: c++

i just want a Simple Calculation to know if i have move my mouse to the Left or Right .
I have mouseDrag(MouseEvent& e), mouseDown(mouseEvent& e) etc.. callbacks
i am able to calculate how much distance i have moved etc..
I want to know that if i am dragging a Component from Left To Right , and suddenly i started dragging from Right to Left, i want to know by calculation that the component is now moving to the Left. 
ex : +1 if i am moving RIGHT , and -1 if i am Moving LEFT. No matter at which point i am .

I am not a mathematics genius, but small this calculation requires really brilliant Logic which i am not able to solve. 
Please help ............

Comment: Er... save the previous value, if `x` increases, you're going right, if it decreases, you're going left? Not sure what other logic you require...?

Comment: Have you tried asking the mouse politely?

Answer (score 3):

What is stored in the `MouseEvent` structure/object? The x coordinate. If it is less that the previous one it has moved to the left. Otherwise to the right.